# Compare two php arrays to see if one is the reverse of the other

Tags: php, arrays, compare

So this may be something simple that I am just over looking, but I need to figure out how to do this. This is a question for a class I'm taking, but am not expecting someone to do my work for me ( I'll never learn that way ) I'm more looking for a good starting point. In this example I needed to create an array, sort it, then reverse it. I got that much down.

The final part is to compare the given array with the possibly reversed version and output “True” if it is a correct reversal and output “False” otherwise. It also needs to be done without using the built in php array functions. I'm still new to programming and want to learn. Any help would be much appreciated as I don't even know where to begin with this last part.
This is what I have so far.

```
<?php

//Original array
$the_array = array(5,9,2,8,3,1,7,6,4);
$arrayString = implode(',',$the_array);
echo ("The original array is: ");
echo $arrayString;
echo "<br />";

//Sort loop
// Compares each value in the array to the next one by seeing if the value is greater then the next +1
// If the value is greater then the next value +1 then it stores the value and moves it into the next position.
for ($j = 0; $j < count($the_array); $j++)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($the_array)-1; $i++)
    {
        if ($the_array[$i] > $the_array[$i+1])
        {
            $tmp = $the_array[$i+1];
            $the_array[$i+1] = $the_array[$i];
            $the_array[$i] = $tmp;
        }
    }
}
$arrayString = implode(',',$the_array);
echo ("The array after sorting is: ");
echo $arrayString;
echo "<br />";

//reversal loop
for ($tmp = sizeof($the_array) - 1; $tmp >= 0; $tmp--)
{
    $reverse[] = $the_array[$tmp]; //New reversed array
}
echo ("The reversed array is: ");
$reverseString = implode(',',$reverse);
echo $reverseString;
```

Any tips in the formatting of my code would also be appreciated.

I actually want to give a thank you to all the responses I got and to the speed of getting them. All the comments and answers have already started to give me a lot of help. I think I may have just been over thinking the problem and some of the things pointed out to me helped me realize this. Thanks again to all.

Comment: why can't you just run your reversing function on the given array, and then compare it the second array to see if it is indeed the reverse of it?

Comment: @Prix: there's no need to know that the array is sorted, the question should be focused on how to determine if 2 arrays are the reverse of each other.

Comment: @DaveChen That's called radical edit and it's not accepted.

Comment: Use functions: `sort($a)`, `reverse($a)` and `checkReverse($a, $b)`.  Given arrays `$a` and `$b` where `$b` is reverse of `$a` in the `checkReverse($a, $b)` function reverse one of them and compare each elements within a loop.  Of course you will have to maintain a boolean flag to store the comparison result.  You can break from the loop as soon as you find the first mismatch.

Comment: Do you explicitly have to do the sorting and reversing long-hand? There are functions (`sort()` and `array_reverse()` respectively) that perform both pieces of functionality.

Comment: @winterblood, first of all, it is a homework and the homework requires not to use built-in function.

Comment: @invisal I stand corrected. I didn't read the second paragraph of the question very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Let `A` be the first array and `B` be the second array
- **If** length of `A` == length of `B` **Then**

  - **For** i = 0 To `LENGTH(A)` - 1

    - **If** `A[i]` != `B[LENGTH(A) - 1 - i]`

      - **Return** False
  - **Return** True
- **Else**

  - **Return** False

Comment: Best answer that doesn't hand-feed a homework solution. +1

Comment: Thanks for giving me a starting point while still making me think about it. I don't want to be spoon fed. Though everyone had really good points and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The easist way of course:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array(3,2,1);

if($array1 == array_reverse($array2)){
    echo 'Reverse duplicates';
}
```

If you can't use array functions then we can loop through using a `for` statement:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array(3,2,1);
$future_array2 = array();

for($x=(count($array1)-1);$x>=0;$x--){
    $future_array2[] = $array2[$x];
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($future_array2),'</pre>';

$array2 = $future_array2;

if($array1 == $array2){
    echo 'Reverse duplicates';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is first of all check that both arrays are of the same length. If they are not so you know that one isn't a reversed of the other.

Next, run an index from start to end of $arr1 and compare it to the length-index of $arr2.

In case you are stuck, code for that will be:

```
function is_reversed($a1, $a2){
    $n = count($a1);
    if ($n != count($a2)){ return false; }
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
        if ($a1[$i] != $a2[$n-1-$i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted was prefectly simple and easy to understand and gave me some good points to think about while constructing my loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overthink it. There's no reason to actually reverse one of the arrays.

You really just need to loop through one array, and compare each element to the one in the corresponding reversed position in the other array. If you find that something doesn't match, you can immediately conclude that your answer is false.

This only works if your arrays are the same length, but if they're not the same length, your answer is automatically false anyways, so you can check for that before you start.

You should be able to do this in under 10 lines of code.

Comment: You were right it took me about 11 lines and that's with some spacing for neatness. It really was a simple problem that I was over thinking.